# Import same XML node with PHP loop

Tags: php, xml

Hello everyone I am trying to create a XML request with multiple same node.

```html
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mainbody>
    <header>
        <company dil="TR">Netgsm</company>
        <usercode>usercode</usercode>
        <password>pass</password>
        <startdate></startdate>
        <stopdate></stopdate>
        <type>1:n</type>
        <msgheader>S.KARABACAK</msgheader>
        </header>
 <body>
     <msg><![CDATA['.$message.']]></msg>
     <no></no>
 </body>
</mainbody>';
```

This is my XML request it is an SMS request sending SMS to numbers in `<no></no>` nodes.

```
$newXML=new SimpleXMLElement($xml); 
$noNode=$newXML->body->no;
$noNode->addChild("no",$new_number);
```

I am getting numbers in databases with a PHP while loop but i couldn't figure out how to add item $xml->body as `<no></no>`

It must be like this

```
<no>number1</no>
<no>number2</no>
<no>number3</no>
```

Comment: how about the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php, see example #10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add child to xml with PHP simpleXml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178062/add-child-to-xml-with-php-simplexml)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: @Thefourthbird `$newXML=new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$noNode=$newXML->body->no;$noNode->addChild("no",$new_number);` I tried this in a while loop but this is give just one <no></no> with all numbers

Comment: @michi I tried them too but still got problem i metioned in above

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `addChild()` from the parent node, which is `<body>`.

```
$newXML->body->addChild("no", "123-456789");
$newXML->body->addChild("no", "987-654321");
$newXML->body->addChild("no", "567-890123");
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/518329

If you want direct access to the new `<no>`, you can reference it with a variable:

```
$newnode = newXML->body->addChild("no", "123-456789"); 
// do something with $newnode
```